# Does ActiveRecord have a way of reporting that a nested attribute model has been destroyed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I am using the `previous_changes` method to determine changes to my ActiveRecord models to pass back via JSON and am wondering if there is something similar to tell me that a nested attribute has been destroyed.

e.g. if `Parent has_many Children` and `Parent accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, allow_destroy: true` I want to be able to do the following.

```
> p = Parent.last
> p.children.length
=> 3
> p.update_attributes {"name"=>"Daddy","children_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"__destroy"=>"1","id"=>"12"}}}
=> true
>p.previous_changes
=> {"name"=>["", "Daddy"], "updated_at"=>[Mon, 27 Aug 2012 22:34:34 EST +10:00, Wed, 29 Aug 2012 10:13:33 EST +10:00]}
>p.destroyed_attributes #Not a real method!!!
=> {"children_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"12"}}}
```

It's that last command that I want. I can whip up my own solution to get this information but I'm hoping there's something tucked away in Rails that will already do this for me.

EDIT:

It doesn't seem that there is a built in way of doing this but I did come up with a solution.
In my parent model I defined a before_save and after_save callback. In the before_save I saved an array of all of the children ids. In the after_save I subtracted an array of all the children ids. Any ids remaining in the array have been deleted! I stored the array in an instance variable of the parent model defined with attr_accessor.

Answer (score 1):

Ad an `:after_destroy followup_tasks` callback to the the detail model (children)

```
def followup_tasks
  #do other stuff
end
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought I'd have to do something like this. Now that I've tried it though, I can't see how to pass something to the parent model from this callback. I have tried setting an instance variable on the parent model but it doesn't appear in the instance of the model in my controller after the child has been deleted. Hmmmmm.

Comment: I've asked another question about this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171216